# Currency exchange percentage of naira and dollar

Tags: real-analysis

If 1 dollar was exchanged for 0.54 naira in 1980, and 1 dollar is exchanged for 416 naira in 2022. What is the percentage decrease in the value of naira?

“I got over 77,000 but I want to make sure I did not solve rubbish.

Comment: If something was originally worth \$2.50, for example, but now is worth only \$0.50, then it has lost $2 of its base value. So it has lost 80% of its value with respect to dollars. That is the model  you should use in this problem.

Comment: How did you get "over 77,000" ? Please explain your steps.